# Get the time slots between the start time and end time

Tags: jquery

I have **start time**, **end time**, and **interval**.

**I have to get the time slots between the start time and end time.**

I have

```
var starttime = "09:50:00";
var endtime = "10:50:00";
var interval = "10";
```

And I want the `time slots` as array

```
var timeslots = ["09:50:00","10:00:00","10:10:00","10:20:00","10:30:00","10:40:00","10:50:00"];
```

The `starttime`, `endtime` and `interval` may vary. How to get the timeslots as desired?

**To add interval to the time** I have:

```
 function addMinutes(time, minsToAdd) {
  function D(J){ return (J<10? '0':'') + J;};
  var piece = time.split(':');
  var mins = piece[0]*60 + +piece[1] + +minsToAdd;

  return D(mins%(24*60)/60 | 0) + ':' + D(mins%60);  
}  //this is working
```

I tried below to generate the `time slot` array.

```
var starttime = "09:50:00";
var interval = "10";
var endtime = "10:50:00";
var timeslots =[stime];


while(starttime ==endtime ){

starttime = addMinutes(starttime , interval); 
timeslots.push(stime);

}
alert(timeslots.length);
```

But the array length shows `1`, means not working...

Please help me to rectify this.. OR help me with any alternative way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't get your addMinutes function to work (chrome kept becoming unresponsive) so I implemented my own.

I don't see where you declared stime but i changed stime to starttime and also changed starttime == endtime to starttime != endtime and the code works.

```
function addMinutes(time, minutes) {
  var date = new Date(new Date('01/01/2015 ' + time).getTime() + minutes * 60000);
  var tempTime = ((date.getHours().toString().length == 1) ? '0' + date.getHours() : date.getHours()) + ':' +
    ((date.getMinutes().toString().length == 1) ? '0' + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes()) + ':' +
    ((date.getSeconds().toString().length == 1) ? '0' + date.getSeconds() : date.getSeconds());
  return tempTime;
}

var starttime = "09:50:00";
var interval = "10";
var endtime = "10:50:00";
var timeslots = [starttime];


while (starttime != endtime) {

  starttime = addMinutes(starttime, interval);
  timeslots.push(starttime);

}
alert(timeslots);
```

**DEMO:**

https://jsfiddle.net/vay9rL7g/

**Result:**

09:50:00,10:00:00,10:10:00,10:20:00,10:30:00,10:40:00,10:50:00

Comment: Unless the interval 'fits' in whole number of times, it will cycle trough day multiple times  (starttime != endtime)

Comment: passing 
var starttime = "00:00:00";
var interval = "60";
var endtime = "23:10:00";
          Convert it into infinite loop

Answer (score 3):

Sample input :

```
var startTime = "10:00",
    endTime = "17:00",
    interval = 30;
```

Sample Output :

```
["10:00", "10:30", "11:00", "11:30", "12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30", "15:00", "15:30", "16:00", "16:30", "17:00"]
```

Source Code:

```
function parseTime(s) {
      var c = s.split(':');
      return parseInt(c[0]) * 60 + parseInt(c[1]);
    }

    function convertHours(mins){
      var hour = Math.floor(mins/60);
      var mins = mins%60;
      var converted = pad(hour, 2)+':'+pad(mins, 2);
      return converted;
    }

    function pad (str, max) {
      str = str.toString();
      return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
    }

    function calculate_time_slot(start_time, end_time, interval = "30"){
        var i, formatted_time;
      var time_slots = new Array();
        for(var i=start_time; i<=end_time; i = i+interval){
        formatted_time = convertHours(i);
        time_slots.push(formatted_time);
      }
      return time_slots;
    }

    var startTime = "10:00";
    var endTime = "17:00";

    var start_time = parseTime(startTime),
        end_time = parseTime(endTime),
        interval = 30;

    var times_ara = calculate_time_slot( start_time, end_time, interval );

    console.log(times_ara);
```

JS Fiddle Link : [Check JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pmza2drg/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
  var starttime = "09:50:00";
  var endtime = "10:50:00";
  var interval = "10";
  var startTimeInMin = convertToMin(starttime);
  var endTimeInMin = convertToMin(endtime);

  timeIntervel = parseInt(endTimeInMin-startTimeInMin)/(parseInt(interval)*60);

  nextSlot = starttime;

  slotArra = [nextSlot];
  for(i=0; i<timeIntervel; i++){
    var nextSlot =  getNextSlot(nextSlot, interval);
    slotArra.push(nextSlot);
  }

  alert(slotArra)

  function convertToMin(inputTime){
    inputTime = inputTime.split(':');
    var hrinseconds = parseInt(inputTime[0])*3600;
    var mininseconds = parseInt(inputTime[1])*60;
    return parseInt(hrinseconds)+parseInt(mininseconds)+parseInt(inputTime[2])
  }

  function getNextSlot(starttime, interval) {
    var piece = starttime.split(':');
    var hour = piece[0];
    var minutes = piece[1];
    var seconds = piece[2];
    var newMinute = parseInt(minutes)+parseInt(interval)
    if(newMinute>=60){
      hour = parseInt(hour)+1;
      newMinute = newMinute%60
      if(newMinute==0)
        newMinute = '00';
    }
    var newTim = hour+':'+newMinute+':'+seconds;
    return newTim;
  } 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```